# Faster way to upscale the screen for a pixelated look in SDL?

Tags: c, performance, sdl, pixel, hardware-acceleration

I'm making a 2D SDL game in C. The native resolution of the game is 160 × 120, which is just before displaying it on the screen upscaled by a certain (integer) scale factor (x1, x2, ...) to give a nice aliased & pixelated indie-like look. Nothing surprising there. However, it has quite a (visible) impact on the game's performance: the higher the scale factor, the higher the impact (obviously).

The code that handles the scaling and displaying is the following:

```
#define GET_PIXEL(surface, x, y) *(Uint32 *)((Uint32 *)surface->pixels + (y * surface->w) + x)

void draw(void) {
    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(screen.native))
        SDL_LockSurface(screen.native);
    for (int i = 0; i < 120; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 160; ++j) {
            SDL_Rect rect = { j * screen.scale, i * screen.scale, screen.scale, screen.scale };
            SDL_FillRect(screen.scaled, &rect, GET_PIXEL(screen.native, j, i));
        }
    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(screen.native))
        SDL_UnlockSurface(screen.native);
    SDL_Flip(screen.scaled);
}
```

The `draw()` function is called every frame. `screen.native` is the 160 × 120 game surface, and `screen.scaled` is the final surface after scaling. Both are 32-bit surfaces created using the `SDL_HWSURFACE` flag.

Is there any better way to do this to improve performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to scale an SDL Surface without clipping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328500/proper-way-to-scale-an-sdl-surface-without-clipping)

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to upscale everything on `load`, not in the `draw` function, and you store the up-scaled version and reuse that. You will be trading memory for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I compiled the latest unstable version of SDL 2.0 (which supports full hardware acceleration) and used only `SDL_Texture`s for a nice constant high FPS, whatever the resolution.